# Saving Values from all Tabs - Android

Tags: android, android-tabhost, android-tablelayout

I have an android layout with 3 tabs. Each tabs contains forms(EditText,Spinner etc). I have a Save button at the end of the layout to save all the inputs from those 3 tabs. How can I go through the tabs to gather the inputs and save the data? Is there is a specific method I could use from the tabhost to access the data in all the tabs at once?

Thanks.

Comment: Where is your save button? means which TAB?

Comment: @Arpit SAVE Button in final tab

Comment: Use static variables.